# ubuntu server: can't access apache hosted pages after changing ip

Tags: apache2, php, firewall

I moved my server to a different office. Since they wanted to access it, I joined their network by changing my server's IP. The server hosts LAMP + postgres.

Now I can't get the basic web apps to run. Even pgadmin from my pc to the server won't run. It's all on a LAN?

What could be the issue?

Eg: /phppgadmin

won't work. not even that index.html that shows 'it works'.

MORE INFO:

I just realised this... When I turn off my firewall with

> ufw disable

I have no problem. How can I now allow this to work with the firewall on? I remember allowing port 22 but it doesn't seem to have an effect. Maybe something I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get WHY this happened... I mean, I WAS using the server without a problem before I took it to the new place and changed its IP.

Anyway, I allowed port 80 (that was running Apache) and this was the solution to the problem.

It is worth mentioning that even before allowing this, I had (and still do) port 22 and 5432 open for PostgreSQL and SSH.

Just allowing the Apache port did the trick.

What made me do this was, when I disabled the firewall, everything was fine. So this gave me the clue that the firewall was the cause.

Also it is worth mentioning that before explicitly allowing port 80, when I tried to connect to PGMyAdmin, it would give me an error about some SSL problem. But this was misleading (at least to me).

Hope someone else finds this useful.